# Facebook Authentication on Android Redirecting to Facebook Android App

Tags: android, facebook-authentication

I am developing an Android app which requires authentication via facebook account.
For the authentication, I used the [Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android) and [Project](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) provided by Facebook

When the mobile does not have the standard facebook app already installed, the authentication works perfectly and my application works.
On the other hand, if the mobile has the Facebook application installed, my application stops working and it goes straight to facebook app after the authentication.

Does anyone knows how can i solve that?

Comment: hi, im developing an android app which requires authentication via facebook account,can you give me sample code to do this, i just only need the facebook authentication only.

Comment: [Here][1] you can find sample codes provided by Facebook. [1]: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using Single Sign On which btw is the right thing to do and it will authorize via Facebook app if it exists on the phone, else redirect via webview dialog. Have you added keyhash of your app into the facebook developer's app?

More instructions on SSO and keyhash here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Few notes about keyhash:

- **Key Hash Reference Doc**: [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).
- **Keytool command not found error**: Keytool is provided by the standard Android SDK. if you get 'Command not found' error, you need to either add its path to your global 'PATH' or go to the folder to run this command. Standard location on Windows is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin and for MAC, its /usr/bin
- **Openssl**: If you don't have openssl, install it from here: [Windows](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), [MAC](http://www.openssl.org/source/). For Mac, follow the instructions [here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread7108.html).
- **Invalid Key Hash**: The keytool silently generates keyhash regardless of unknown debug.keystore location or wrong password. When running the sample app, use adb logcat to track errors. The error returned for invalid key is *Facebook-authorize( 2631): Login failed: invalid_key*. Visual indication of invalid keyhash is when SSO slides in and out of the Facebook app without prompting any screen or GDP dialog. If you get this error, there are few possibilities:

  - keytool couldn't find your debug.keystore location. Make sure you provide the correct path. One way to know is keytool should always ask for password when it has the correct location.
  - The password you entered is incorrect. The default Keystore password: "android".
  - You need to click 'Save Changes' when adding keyhash to the Developer App on Facebook.
  - If this all fails, try using cygwin or linux box to generate hashkey.

Comment: I am developing this Android app with the author of the question (Rafael) and the problem was the default Keystore password. When I put "android" as you said, it worked! Before publishing my app on Android Market I shall generate another key, following the "Signing Your Applications" docs right? PS: Rafael will soon accept your answer, thanks!